# CakePHP AppController strange behaviour

Tags: cakephp

I'm following the CakePHP (latest) Bookmarkers tutorial (Part 2 - Auth). Everything is going correctly until I get to adding the following in the AppController.php file:

```
'authorize' => 'Controller',
```

which then stops me from being able to access either the Users list or the Tags list. I can only see the Bookmarks list. I have been through the tutorial twice. First time I typed out all the code, then did a full reinstall of the framework and cut'n'pasted the code, testing at each paste and it seems that this line breaks the app. The controller method in full is supposed to look like this:

```
public function initialize()
{
$this->loadComponent('Flash');
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authorize'=> 'Controller', //added this line - it breaks stuff
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()  // added this line - not sure if it breaks stuff on its own
]);

// Allow the display action so our pages controller
// continues to work.
$this->Auth->allow(['display']);
```

}

and it is the 'authorized' and 'unauthorizedRedirect' values in the initialize() method that break the example. Has anyone come across this behaviour also?
In Firefox, I get a page saying the page isn't redirecting properly. Comment out those two lines and all works fine...

Comment: replace 'authorize'=>'User' in your code where User is your Controller name....

Comment: Yes, @PruthvirajChudasama is right. you need to give name of your UserController.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that you need to loggedin for accessing any URL of your application. If you want to access some URL without login then add it in the controller like `$this->Auth->allow('index');`